# bootstrap navbar, customize brand to an image hanging

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to try out the logo similar to [adobe](http://www.adobe.com/) hanging from the navabar. but I couldn't do it using bootstrap.

Any thoughts?

http://jsfiddle.net/EFTTp/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner"> <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
 <a class="brand" href="index.html"> <img style="height:50px;" src="http://kpv.s3.amazonaws.com/static/img/logo.jpg"></a>

        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav pull-left">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html" class="scroller">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="pricing.html" class="scroller">Pricing</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="knowledge.html" class="scroller">FAQ</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please see @Suresh's answer, it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EFTTp/4/)**

try this css:
Try position absolute.
Give position relative to the parent div and give position absolute to child div.

```
.navbar-inner{
    position:relative;
    padding-left:70px;
}
.navbar .brand {                
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #f00;        
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Nice. +1. @Kiarash, the trick is to use position: absolute; with top and left values on the image that you want hanging.

Comment: Thanks, How can I make the image to scale on different monitors? right   now some times it's huge and some times small...